# Get-VM command with -Location parameter returns one result then error

Tags: vmware-esxi, scripting, powercli

i'm writing a powerCLI script and i'm facing a strange behaviour.

I use connect-VIserver with administrator@vsphere.local account to connect to my VCSA 6.7 U2 server. If i use Get-VM cmdlet without any parameter it returns all VMs without problems. Then i would get a list of VMs on a particular ESXi host.
BUT when i launch:
Get-VM -Location "esxi server name" 
it returns only one result (of 25vms present on that host), then error.

```
PowerCLI C:\> Get-VM -Location $sum

Name                 PowerState Num CPUs MemoryGB
----                 ---------- -------- --------
GIUDECCA             PoweredOn  4        16,000
Get-VM : 05/12/2019 16:07:43    Get-VM          Eccezione generata dalla destina
zione di
una chiamata.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-VM -Location $sum
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-VM], VimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_BaseCmdlet_UnknownError,VMware.VimAutomatio
   n.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.GetVM
```

As you see in the code i posted i tried to use the parameter with a variable, using Get-VMHost -Name "esxi server name". but same error.
What i am doing wrong?

O.S. Windows 7
Powershell 5.1
PowerCLI 6.5

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the solution, maybe was an incompatibility between version installed.
I opened a Powershell and installed powercli modules from PSGallery.
Now it works.